# MSBuild string that has this format $(SomeText)

Tags: msbuild

in my MSBuild every text that has this pattern $(SomeText) is considered as property reference.  I have an MSBuild Custom Task that writes content to some text file and the text that needs to be written is $(SomeText) thus MSBuild does not let this pass through because it is considered as properry reference.

Any workaround.

Many thanks,

Idriss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSBuild uses same escaping as in URL. Use `%24` instead of $

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60ecse8t(VS.80).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hxt0028(VS.80).aspx) is a full list of ASCII character codes